# Finding a ordered subsequence (not necessarily continuous) from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am stuck with a problem. I have a list for e.g. `[A,B,C,D,E]`. the size of the list may vary. I have to check whether a sub-sequence for e.g. `[A,C,E]` occurs in the main list. The size of the sub-sequence may also vary.

The problem here is that the sub-sequence here need not be continuous. Just the order of occurrence matters.

Some examples:

```
seq = [A,B,C,D,E]

subseq = [A,C,E]
>>>sub-sequence present in sequence

subseq = [B,D,E]
>>> sub-sequence present in sequence

subseq = [A,E]
>>> sub-sequence present in sequence

subseq = [C,B]
>>> sub-sequence not present in sequence

subseq = [B,A,E]
>>> sub-sequence not present in sequence
```

Comment: Why not write an algorithm that loops through the list and keeps track of the occuring elements that form the subsequence?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) to produce an iterator whose consumption enforces order on each member check.

```
def subcheck(li, sub_li):
    it = iter(li)
    return all(el in it for el in sub_li)
```

**Demo**

```
In[95]: subcheck([1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2], [1, 9, 3])
Out[95]: False

In[96]: subcheck([1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2], [1, 3, 9])
Out[96]: True
```

---

This approach works because the `in` keyword for a list is implemented as a sequence iteration ([the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in)):

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

Comment: Very nice use of the iterator!

Answer (score 2):

You could easily write a recursive solution if you want to understand how to solve similar problems:

```
def isPresent(subseq,seq):
    if not subseq:
        return True
    elif not seq:
        return False
    elif subseq[0]==seq[0]:
        return isPresent(subseq[1:],seq[1:])
    else:
        return isPresent(subseq,seq[1:])
```

called like `isPresent(['A','C','E'],['A','B','C','D','E'])`

Comment: Recursion is nice to see, especially if this is educational. One critique - can you please fix the indentation? Also, it may make a bit more sense for your function to return `True` or `False`, but that's up to you. You could also recurse via list index as opposed to slicing to avoid making copies of the list on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a fairly simple iterative solution as long as both inputs are iterable.

```
def subseq(sub, seq):
    if not sub:
        return True
    it = iter(sub)
    curr = next(it)
    for item in seq:
        if item == curr:
            try:
                curr = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                return True
    return False
```